# Python aiohttp returning 500 error while requests works fine

Tags: python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am pinging a company's internal api with DELETE and POST requests, json included. When doing so with the requests library everything works fine.

When doing so with aiohttp using asyncio.gather() I often get a "500" error response: "Failed... : ...Exception". The DELETE request works every time, but the POST requests don't. The first POST request returns this error about 10% of the time. The second or third POST requests return the error about 50% of the time, and if there are 10 or more requests, each request returns the error as much as 90% of the time. The error is random: each time I retry it will happen to different requests in the list.

I thought perhaps it was the speed of the async requests but when I time.sleep(1) in between requests I get the same results. I then looked to see if the server was reading the json, but when I excluded the posted json I got a different error that the server could not read the json.

What else it could be?

edit: Here's the essential extrapolated code:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
   await asyncio.gather(*[ping_api(session, item) for item in items])
```

```
async def ping_api(session, item)
   data = {'foo': item}
   try: 
        r = await session.post('https://random-company', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, json=data)
```

if I replace the await aiohttp session in ping_api with a regular requests session, the data is retrieved perfectly.

Comment: Are you sending requests in parallel when using `requests`? And are you doing so when using `aiohttp`? Could you show some of your code?

Comment: Please update the question to include the exact code you tried running with `asyncio` and `requests`.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do that when the code is embedded in long complex functions, including proprietary information?